# Is there are some ways to know on which subsample of data the XGBoost tree was fitted?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, boosting

I'm making some XGBoost practice and I'd like to know on which subset of data the trees of XGBRegressor was fitted. Here the list of params that I use:

```
params = {'learning_rate': 0.09, 
          'n_estimators': 5,
          'objective': 'reg:squarederror',
          'max_depth': 6,
          'subsample': 0.2 
         }
```

I'm working with Python 3.7 and XGBoost library. So is there some way to know that? I've read the doc but couldn't find some useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily draw the tree and check it out
you can do it with

```
export_graphiviz(uralgo,"filename",feature_names,rounded=True)
```

Comment: it shows  only a tree, but I need an indexes or rows of my dataset that were used to fit that tree