# Are There Ways to Identify Which Subsample of Data an XGBoost Tree Was Fitted On?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, xgbclassifier

I want to determine which specific rows of samples (according to the subsample parameter) are randomly chosen for each tree's training. For instance, with a training set of 100 rows and a subsample rate of 0.7, I want to know the exact 70 rows selected for the training of each tree. I've been searching for a solution everywhere but have had no luck.

Comment: Related (unanswered) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60169306/is-there-are-some-ways-to-know-on-which-subsample-of-data-the-xgboost-tree-was-f?rq=2